# how to put map values into list with different type?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

1. I have `map<Integer,Object>`
2. I want to put values of the map to te `List<String>`
3. The `ArrayList<String>(map.values)` gives me a error
4. `The constructor ArrayList<String>(Collection<Object>) is undefined`

EDIT:
Thank you. But I did not make myself clear. My object are class objects name TravelData which have few variables like doubles, dates and strings. I processing them and put into map like `<Integer,TravelData>.` Then i must to put them to `List<String>` and print them all. I cant change type of list :(

**solved by: Override toString method**

```
multiLangOffers = new ArrayList<String>();
for (TravelData value : offers.values()) {
    multiLangOffers.add(value.toString());
}
```

Thank you all !

Comment: Your `Collection` specifies that it might contain any `Object`. Your `List` can only contain instances of `String`. If your map values are all actually strings, fix your map definition.

Comment: Otherwise you won't get around doing this manually, calling `toString()` on your objects, if that's what you want.

Comment: When it is TravelData, then please provide us the Interface of this class and which value you want in your List.

Comment: why dont you add toString to ur TravelData and at printing time iterate through entry sets and get value means your traveldata and print that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on that you initialized your Map with `<Integer, Object>` a call to `Map.values()` will return `Collection<Object>`.
This means you had to initialize your `ArrayList` as:

```
List<Object> value = ArrayList<Object>(map.values());
```

But this would be useless, because the return of `map.values()` is already a collection and when you are not depending on API parts of Interface `List` you could stick to that.

But you want a `List<String>` with the values of the Map which are String then you have to do something like this:

```
List<String> stringValues = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Object value : map.values()) {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        stringValues.add((String) value);
    }
}
```

This is iterating over all Values as Objects and then checks the instance type of value on String. if so, add the value as String to your List.

So makes the questions strange, but depending on comment.
If the map is handling custom complex Object instead of `Object`. Then you have to access the desired String value of that Object manualy:

```
List<String> stringValues = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ComplexObj value : map.values()) {
    stringValues.add(value.getDesiredStringValueGetterMethodIfYouUseBeanSyntax());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I did not make myself clear. My object are class objects name TravelData which have few variables like doubles, dates and strings. I processing them and put into map like <Integer,TravelData>. Then i must to put them to List<String> and print them all. I cant change type of list :(

Comment: Thanks i override toString method and call out it like u tell me above.

Answer (score 3):

**Any Collection can be passed as an argument to the constructor as long as its type extends the type of the ArrayList**

**but here you are doing reverse as object can not be passed in string as it doesn't extends string**

you can do two thing

1. you can make list of objects and all will work find

   ```
   public class Test {
     static List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
     static Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     public static void main(String args[]) {
           map.put("1", "test");
           list = new ArrayList<Object>(map.values());
           System.out.println(list.toString());
     }
   }
   ```
2. you can make map with value of type string

   ```
   public class Test {
     static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     public static void main(String args[]) {
       map.put("1", "test");
       list = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());
       System.out.println(list.toString());
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try that `List list = new ArrayList(map.values());`

Regards

Comment: gives me an error 
TravelData cannot be cast to java.lang.String